# Warning: number_format() expects at least 1 parameter, 0 given

Tags: php

Can you guys help me solve this error?

```
<?php echo'<td><strong>'.str_pad($i+1, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT).'</strong>x de <strong>R$ '.number_format($valorParcela,2,',','.'). ' sem juros</strong></td>' .number_format() ?> </option>
```

Comment: Why is it that there's an extra number_format()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got an extra call to `number_format` at the end of your string. Remove it:

```
<?php echo'<td><strong>' 
        . str_pad($i+1, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT) 
        . '</strong>x de <strong>R$ '
        . number_format($valorParcela,2,',','.')
        . ' sem juros</strong></td>' ?>
</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove extra number_format and add semi colon before the php ending tag ?>:

```
    <?php 

    echo'<td><strong>'
   .str_pad($i+1, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT)
   .'</strong>x de <strong>R$ '
   .number_format($valorParcela,2,',','.')
   . ' sem juros</strong></td>';
    ?> 
</option>
```